# How can I add dependency to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have eclipse IDE 3.6 , I want to use maven plugin for eclipse so I added the Eclipse     IAM update site at http://q4e.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite-iam/

How can I add the following :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

so I can use UriBuilder

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is now best to use the official **[m2e "Maven for Eclipse" plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)**, instead of an old project.

> The goal of the m2ec project is to provide a first-class Apache Maven support in the Eclipse IDE, making it easier to edit Maven's `pom.xml`, run a build from the IDE and much more.
>   `m2e` is also a platform that let others provide better integration with additional Maven plugins (e.g. Android, web development, etc.)

See its [update sites](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/).